# If $F$ decreasing closed sequence then $\cap_{n=1}^{\infty}F_n\not= \emptyset$

Tags: measure-theory

> If $F$ decreasing closed sequence and $F_1$ is bounded then
>
> $\cap_{n=1}^{\infty}F_n\not= \emptyset$

Attempt at a proof: Let assume that that $\cap_{n=1}^{\infty}F_n= \emptyset$ (to arrive at a contradiction) so 
$\forall \not{\exists}n: x_n\in F_n$

but $F_{n+1}\subset F_n \subset \dots \subset F_1 $

How to continue? must $F_1$ be bounded?

Comment: You might be interested in the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_intersection_property. By the way, shouldn't the setup be "let $F_n$ be a decreasing sequence of non empty closed sets and let $F_1$ be bounded"

Comment: @b00nheT we assume they are not empty as then the proof is over, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, I think so.

Answer (score 1):

This is true only if the closed sets are compact. Pick, for example, the sets $F_n=[n,+\infty)$. They are all closed sets, the sequence is decreasing, but $\cap F_n=\emptyset$. By this counterexample, we get that $F_1$ must be bounded.

Conversely, if $F_1$ is bounded and closed, then as a property of $\mathbb R^n$, $F_1$ is a compact set, so it follows that it has the finite intersection property.